timeout issue on supabase rpc calling a function to refresh materialized view
im working on a supabase x python projet and need to run a REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY call via my python code. I believe the only way to do this is via supabase rpc on a function.
this is the function i'm running:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_core_transactions()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
  REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY core_transactions;
END;
$$;

the issue is that i keep running into timeouts. I have tried setting different statment timeouts for roles and for the session. I have tried the below for initializing the supabase client in python.
supabase: Client = create_client(
    url, 
    key,
    options=ClientOptions(
        postgrest_client_timeout=600,    # 10 minutes
        storage_client_timeout=600,      # 10 minutes
        schema="public",
    )
)

Nothing appears to work. I keep getting timeouts after 2 minutes.
All other posts on timeouts dont refer to supabase rpcs on functions.
Hope someone has an idea what to do here.
thanks!

There are more timeouts that you can try to reconfigure here. It would help if you share the timeout error message. Here supabase also recommends setting an individual timeout for the function
